# How to get entire email message text / body / content in Gmail API? C#

Tags: c#, email, gmail-api

I'm using the Gmail API to create a WPF app which can read and send emails.

**I am able to get the "from", "to", the email subject etc. but I am unable to get the message body / content / all text in it.**

I've tried:

- `string messageContent = message.Raw;` ---> message.Raw is always null
- `string messageContent = message.Payload.Body.Data` ---> always null
- `string messageContent = message.Payload.Parts[0].Body.Data` ---> always null
- foreach (var part in message.Payload.Parts)
  {
  byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(part.Body.Data);
  string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
  MessageBox.Show(decodedString);
  }

--->  throws `System.FormatException: „The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.”`

I get the emails with this way:

```
Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message message = await service.Users.Messages.Get("me", ((ListViewItem)(sender)).Tag as string).ExecuteAsync();
            foreach (var header in message.Payload.Headers)
            {
                if (header.Name == "From")
                    from = header.Value;
                else if (header.Name == "To")
                    to = header.Value;
                else if (header.Name == "Subject")
                    subject = header.Value;
            }
```

The sender's (ListViewItem) tag contains the email id that was loaded previously. This is a part of a ListViewItem's click event.

**Is there any working way to get the content of an email with Gmail API?**

Comment: If the payload, body and data are all null, how do you expect `Convert.FromBase64String` to work at all? How is `message` retrieved? Does it contain an actual response? Or is it a default value that wasn't replaced with the response? Post the code that actually retrieves this message

Comment: I've read some similar questions and this was one of the answers, so I checked if it works.

Comment: Obviously not. Post your code. `Convert.FromBase64String(x)` won't produce anything if `x` is empty. If `part` is `message.Payload.Parts[0]`, you're actually executing `Convert.FromBase64String(null)`

Comment: I see that, I just didn't notice it at first.